# How to configure the mirror http://mirror.ctan.org/ redirects to?

Tags: fonts, texlive, ctan

I'm using vanilla TeXLive 2013 in ubuntu 13.10.
Here, running `getnonfreefonts-sys --all` fails to download
`arial.zip` and all such files. I think this is because the mirror
closest to me (`http://tezcatl.fciencias.unam.mx/tex-archive`) redirects
`http:` to `ftp:`, and the firewall blocks such traffic. I have succesfully configured `tlmgr` to use another mirror, but for some reason `getnonfreefonts` does not pick it up.

Comment: to install nonfree fonts you should get this [script](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts) and then issue a `texlua install-getnonfreefonts`. Have you done that?

Comment: @dcmst Yes, I have.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. The address resolution is managed by ctan.org. However `getnonfreefonts-sys` has the option `--http` that should do what you want.

Comment: @egreg i don't think `--http` would work.  i've tried retrieving `arial.zip` from that site  -- via my browser -- and it doesn't work -- says “`starting ftp transaction`” and does nothing more.  i have therefore suggested that we should summarily remove the site from the `mirror.ctan.org` lists -- will post here if my colleagues agree (in which case, it's no more than un-ticking something in the database).

Comment: Indeed, what @wasteofspace describes is what happens to me in that machine, running `getnonfreefonts-sys` with the --http option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as we (the ctan team) know, there's no direct answer.

so we've removed the `unam.mx` mirror from the selection.

probably easiest to address such messages to `ctan` (at) `dante.de` though i do look here pretty regularly (i suspect i'm alone among recipients of that mail list in doing so...)